# What is Catbug up to off camera?

Tags: bravest-warriors

In the episode [Catbug's Away Team](http://youtu.be/RrviEBJyx3g?t=3m33s) of the show *Bravest Warriors*, Catbug leads an away team down to a planet.  While there, he tries to help the locals with several problems.  Some of them are shown on camera, like the *super Chinese peanut butter ice cream* and *herding turtles into a giant pie shell*.

The remaining ones are all off-camera, but we do get to hear Catbug describing them.  Unfortunately, I'm having trouble understanding his voice (as he's played by a six year old).

**What are the problems he helps with off camera?**

What I've gotten so far:

- something about a baseball team and a hippo
- billy goats stuck in a car wash
- something about firemen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [closed captions](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/100078?hl=en-GB) on the video you've linked;

> **"That baseball team is trying to hot-glue a wig on the hippo!"**
>
> **"That fireman is trying to draw an indy comic about his own life!"**
>
> **"That squirrel can't balance on that candy-cane!"**
>
> **"Those billy-goats are trapped in the car wash!"**

at the end he yells

> **"Potty Break!"**

Comment: Thanks, at the time I asked the question, the video didn't have any closed captions yet.

Comment: Nice one. Looks a fun episode too...